# How to select combination of rows from df based on colum value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df in the following format:

```
                        open    close extremes
datetime                                 
2021-06-25 14:56:00  1.19432  1.19438        H
2021-06-25 15:04:00  1.19386  1.19378        L
2021-06-25 15:14:00  1.19408  1.19392        L
2021-06-25 15:18:00  1.19393  1.19405        H
2021-06-25 15:19:00  1.19405  1.19392        L
2021-06-25 15:27:00  1.19403  1.19413        H
2021-06-25 15:33:00  1.19412  1.19393        L
2021-06-25 15:38:00  1.19407  1.19395        L
2021-06-25 15:44:00  1.19406  1.19398        L
2021-06-25 15:50:00  1.19409  1.19404        L
```

I want to return only the last LHL pattern in the `extremes` column, i.e. in this case:

```
                        open    close extremes
datetime                                 
2021-06-25 15:19:00  1.19405  1.19392        L
2021-06-25 15:27:00  1.19403  1.19413        H
2021-06-25 15:33:00  1.19412  1.19393        L
```

I tried tinkering with the `.isin()` method but realized that doing something like: `df[df['extremes'].isin(['L','H','L'])]` would just return the same dataframe. I managed to set up a test to check if the df even contains the LHL pattern:
`if "LHL" in "".join(df['extremes'].tolist())` and I was thinking that I could match all LHL sequences in `"".join(df['extremes'].tolist()`, get the index of the last match, and check that index in the dataframe - but I have the assumption I overcomplicate it and there might be much nicer pandatic solutions.

Comment: Please provide code to produce your dataframe

Comment: @ifly6 you can just use the df provided above and read it in as a txt file. That df has two different LHL patterns to illustrate the problem.

Comment: The delimiter isn't clear. Using a delimiter `\s+` or `\s{2,}` fails to produce results. This is because of your data frame's printing format. Either print the CSV representation or the datetime in a non-index column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use shift, like this:

```
s = df['extremes']

# create a mask with your conditions, to find the midpoint of the window
m = (s.shift(-1) == 'L') & (s == 'H') & (s.shift() == 'L')
# determin index of the center of the last window meeting your conditions
last = m[::-1].idxmax()

# filter dataframe based on the window
df[s.index.isin(range(last-1,last+2))]
```

**Output:**

```
     datetime datetime h     open    close extremes
4  25.06.2021   15:19:00  119.405  119.392        L
5  25.06.2021   15:27:00  119.403  119.413        H
6  25.06.2021   15:33:00  119.412  119.393        L
```

**Sample data to test:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': {0: '25.06.2021', 1: '25.06.2021', 2: '25.06.2021', 3: '25.06.2021', 4: '25.06.2021', 5: '25.06.2021', 6: '25.06.2021', 7: '25.06.2021', 8: '25.06.2021', 9: '25.06.2021'}, 'datetime h': {0: '14:56:00', 1: '15:04:00', 2: '15:14:00', 3: '15:18:00', 4: '15:19:00', 5: '15:27:00', 6: '15:33:00', 7: '15:38:00', 8: '15:44:00', 9: '15:50:00'}, 'open': {0: 119.432, 1: 119.38600000000001, 2: 119.40799999999999, 3: 119.39299999999999, 4: 119.405, 5: 119.40299999999999, 6: 119.412, 7: 119.40700000000001, 8: 119.406, 9: 119.40899999999999}, 'close': {0: 119.43799999999999, 1: 119.37799999999999, 2: 119.39200000000001, 3: 119.405, 4: 119.39200000000001, 5: 119.413, 6: 119.39299999999999, 7: 119.395, 8: 119.398, 9: 119.404}, 'extremes': {0: 'H', 1: 'L', 2: 'L', 3: 'H', 4: 'L', 5: 'H', 6: 'L', 7: 'L', 8: 'L', 9: 'L'}})
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce your data frame so I can't provide a fully proofed answer. That said...

If you use `df['extremes'].shift(-1)` and `df['extremes'].shift(1)` to create two new columns, which have the 'previous' and 'next' values for any specific row, then concatenate the three columns in order using `s = df['extremes_-1'] + df['extremes'] + df['extremes_1']` (or whatever you name them) you'll have a column against which you can directly apply your `"LHL"` value against.

Then just subset to `df[s == 'LHL']`.

Answer (score 2):

Similar logic to Andreas, but a different mask with XOR:

```
>>> h = df['extremes'].eq('H')
>>> pattern = (h ^ h.shift()) & (h ^ h.shift(-1)) & h
>>> i = df.index.get_loc(df.index[pattern].max())
>>> print(df.iloc[i-1:i+2, :])
                        open    close extremes
datetime                                      
2021-06-25 15:19:00  1.19405  1.19392        L
2021-06-25 15:27:00  1.19403  1.19413        H
2021-06-25 15:33:00  1.19412  1.19393        L
```